# Is a compact set of distributions still compact if we fix the marginal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, compactness

Let $\mathcal{P}_{X,Y}$ be a collection of  joint probability measure of $(X,Y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.   Suppose that  $\mathcal{P}_{X,Y}$ is sequentially compact in the topology of weak convergence.

**My question:** Given a marginal distribution $P_X$, is the following set sequentially compact?

\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}_{X,Y,P_X}=\{ P_{XY} \in \mathcal{P}_{X,Y}: P_X  \text{ is a marginal of }  P_{XY}\}. 
\end{align}

In other, we fixing a marginal distribution.

**My argument:**  If  $\mathcal{P}_{X,Y}$ is sequentially compact than any sequence $ \{P_{X_n,Y_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has a subsequence that converges in $\mathcal{P}_{X,Y}$.   This also implies to the sequence  $ \{P_{X,Y_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ where the marginal is fixed.  That is a sequnce $\{P_{X,Y_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has a convergent subsquence   $\{P_{X,Y_n}\}_{n_k=1}^\infty$  that convergence in $\mathcal{P}_{X,Y}$, but every elemetn of  $\{P_{X,Y_n}\}_{n_k=1}^\infty$ is also in $\mathcal{D}_{X,Y,P_X}$. So, this subsequence convergence in $\mathcal{D}_{X,Y,P_X}$.  Therefore, $\mathcal{D}_{X,Y,P_X}$ is sequentially compact.

This is a correct argument?

Comment: You have a gap.  The $P_{X,Y_n}$ will, after passing to a subsequence, converge to some probability measure $P$, but you have to prove that $P$ still has marginal $P_X$.  In other words, you have to prove that the space of all measures having marginal $P_X$ is (sequentially) closed.

Comment: @NateEldredge  I see. Do you know how I would go about showing that?

Comment: Try to show the following: a measure $P$ has marginal $P_X$ iff for every bounded continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x) \,P(dx,dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\, P_X(dx)$.  Now this holds for all $P_n$, and $f(x)$ is a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so you may pass to the limit on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more direct argument is the following, based on the idea that Nate Eldridge mentions in his comment:  A probability measure $P$ has margin $Q$ if, for all bounded continuous $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, we have  $P(f\otimes1) = \iint_{\mathbb R^2} f(x)P(dx,dy) = Q(f) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) Q(dx)$, where $f\otimes1:(x,y)\mapsto f(x)$.  Thus  $$\{P:P\text{ has margin }Q \}=\bigcap_{f\in C_b(\mathbb R)} \{ P:P(f\otimes1) = Q(f)\}.$$  But for each $f$ the map $P\mapsto P(f\otimes1)$ is continuous, so the set of $P$ such that $P(f\otimes1)=Q(f)$ is closed.  So the set of $P$ with margin $Q$ is the intersection of closed sets, and hence closed.

Finally, if $K$ is a compact set of probability measures on $\mathbb R^2$, the subset of $K$ of measures with margin $Q$ is a closed subset of $K$, and hence also compact.